# How to show loader image before popup screen of color box module in drupal 7

Tags: javascript

I used color-box module in my current drupal project for showing user details in popup after click user image. It will take some time to show details so I want to show loader images before this. I tried to override this using drupal.behaviors but cannot get proper output. If any idea how to handle this situation then please help me for same.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this will help you,

- You can use [Colorbox Callbacks](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/#setting-retinaSuffix)

  - **onOpen** : Callback that fires right before Colorbox begins to open
  - **onComplete** : Callback that fires right after loaded content is displayed

  ```
  jQuery.colorbox({ 
  ........
    onOpen:function(){
      //show loader
    }
    onComplete:function(){ 
     //hide loader
    }
  });
  ```

Answer (score 0):

by default colorbox shows a default loader depending on the theme you select, you can always change that image via css

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$("#cboxLoadingOverlay")` since it will be hidden after colorboxContent is loaded

```
 onOpen: function() {
                $("#cboxLoadingOverlay").html("<img width='128' src='/images/loaders/ajax-loader.gif' alt='Loading....'/>")
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You should try this.

```
fastIframe: false
```